# How do I login to my Mojang account on my minecraft app?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I created a new Mojang account because I forgot my password on my old one, so on minecraft I can't join servers because it keeps saying enter password for my old account. How do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't there a "Forgot Password" option?

Comment: Nope can't find one

Comment: Can you please describe what happens in more detail? As far as I understand, you forgot the password for your old account. How do you log in to Minecraft - is the old password saved in the game, or are you entering the new one? Did you buy Minecraft for your new account?

Comment: You can reset Monjang account password at, suddenly, Mojang website: https://account.mojang.com/password

Comment: @OrcJMR post that as an answer

Comment: Ignoring the blaring XY problem, If you're able to launch the game then the request may be from the server you're joining in which case you'll need to contact them to migrate your player data and/or re-whitelist you. But first use password reset. Post a screen shot showing the error, I've only had that issue when mc login servers were offline because if you login with launcher it should never ask again for password unless login servers go down before you join server.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to reset password to a Mojang account on Mojang's website:

https://account.mojang.com/password